# Highlight query in search results in special characters

Tags: php, highlight, substr

I have this PHP code to highlight the Query on search results.

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['k'])){
        $k = htmlentities($_REQUEST['k']);
        $position = 0;

        while ($position = stripos($text, $k, ($position)?$position+30:0) and $position !== false){
            $text = substr_replace($text, '</span>', $position + strlen($k), 0 );
            $text = substr_replace($text, '<span class="highlight">', $position, 0);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I search something like "cafe", there might be results with "café" (é) and that terms won't be highlighted...

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accent-insensitive substring matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582916/accent-insensitive-substring-matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a link that includes a normalization array and several examples of what I think you are trying to acheive -  https://www.php.net/strtr